# Windows Phone 8 - Interstitial Ads Only Display Once

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I manged to get adMob interstitial ads working on my phone app. However, they only serve one ad and then no more ads are served. its as if i need to 'reset' the adrequest or something but i cant find much information other than the adMob example that does not serve ads repeatedly.

What happens in the code below is that once the 'count' hits 5 in the button, i want an add to show. It works one time only.

Any ideas?  Thank you so much.

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    /* Intersitial*/
    private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

    int countAds = 0;
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        /* Intersitial */
        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd("MY_ID");
        adRequest = new AdRequest();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        countAds++;
        if (countAds >= 5)
        {
            interstitialAd.ReceivedAd += OnAdReceived;
            interstitialAd.LoadAd(adRequest);

            countAds = 0;
        }
    }

     /* Intersital */
    private void OnAdReceived(object sender, AdEventArgs e)
    {

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Ad received successfully");
        interstitialAd.ShowAd();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this Demo. plz chek it. Sure it work for u. Give Your App Id in Your Button Click.

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
    int Click1 = 0;
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();          

     }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Click1++;
        if (Click1 == 5)
        {
            interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd("My APp Id");
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();

              interstitialAd.ReceivedAd += OnAdReceived;
            interstitialAd.LoadAd(adRequest);
            Click1 = 0;
        }
    }
    private void OnAdReceived(object sender, AdEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Ad received successfully");
        interstitialAd.ShowAd();   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You should try to call your show method in the main page constructor. so admob ads wll b shown when Your application launch again n again.. and you can also use  interstitialAd.ShowAd() where you want to shown your Ads.

Comment: Thanks but I need the advert to show on each '5th click' of the button. I tried to use: interstitialAd.ShowAd(); in the button but an ad does not display.